# Basic hand (touchless) gesture detection, solution needed

Tags: gpio, hardware, i2c

I need a good solution for basic gesture recognition (touchless), like swipe left, up, down, right, "tap" hardware/software for Raspberry Pi.

I've seen http://www.hoverlabs.co/#hover which looks very cool, but doesn't seem suited for something that could be hidden inside say a panel frame. Can it be enclosed at all? If it is based on capacitance then maybe not.

[image]

I've experimented with both PIR sensors and IR emitter/detectors. Both of which work but each have their issues. A pair of PIR or IR sensors can in theory detect swipe direction. But it would be great if there was a nice packaged solution with software for this.

I know there are techniques for using a camera to detect gestures, but I'm hoping for something simpler and 99% accurate.

Need something small that can be effectively hidden (maybe some small holes or ir transmissive plastic covering it).

Comment: This is not a Raspberry Pi question. I suggest you move it to http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Capacitive solutions can work through (thin) but completely sealed enclosures - if they are non-conductive (polymers). I believe Atmel offers dedicated both dedicated controllers (QTouch) as well as generic microcontroller based solutions to do so (see http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42208-Low-Cost-Capacitive-Touch-TV-Control-Keypad_AP-Note_AT01486.pdf ). And yes, the question might get better answers at electronics.SE

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, it can be enclosed : https://www.tindie.com/products/ootsidebox/3dpad-touchless-gesture-controller-arduino-shield/

Comment: If you are the creator you should disclose it. Good product by the way! :)